# Labels not showing in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a beginner, and trying to learn C#, XAML, VS2017, Xamarin.Forms, SQLite, all at the same time from scratch.
(not in college, just on my own)
on each Navigation Page, I can see some of the Labels displayed.
But when I try to have more than 4 Labels, new Labels bump off an older one.
I know I'm not getting lost in the weeds of fancy Layouts and Formatting.
Just trying to simply display the data collected so far.

Is this some limitation built into `XAML`?
Or am I missing something else entirely?

**Xaml code:**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="name"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displaySoulNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayPersonalityNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayPowerNameNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayBirthDayNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayAttitudeNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayLifePathNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label x:Name="displayDestinyNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**The c# code:**

```
//pull from db
name.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.Symbol;
displaySoulNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplaySoulNumber;
displayPersonalityNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayPersonalityNumber;
displayPowerNameNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayPowerNameNumber;
displayBirthDayNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayBirthDayNumber;
displayAttitudeNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayAttitudeNumber;
displayLifePathNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayLifePathNumber;
displayDestinyNumber.Text = ConnectionClass.stock.DisplayDestinyNumber;
```

[image]

Comment: It can be just a lack of space issue. Set the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of the StackLayout to `FillAndExpand`and see if anything changes.

Comment: Are you referring to the space between Birthday and Destiny? If that's the case it's because technically your `Label` elements for "Attitude" and "LifePath" are still present, they just don't have a value...however they'll still consume the space of the `Label` as an empty string when displayed in the DOM. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be some space issues. You can try wrapping you `StackLayout` on a `ScrollView` like this :

```
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="name"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displaySoulNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayPersonalityNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayPowerNameNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayBirthDayNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayAttitudeNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayLifePathNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>

    <Label x:Name="displayDestinyNumber"
           FontSize="Medium"/>
</StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, of course. i had messed up the naming of the stored items.